# how to properly validate a Random Forest classifier model?

Tags: classification, random-forest, validation

I have read in the webpage given by the creators of the RF model the following:

"The out-of-bag (oob) error estimate
In random forests, there is no need for cross-validation or a separate test set to get an unbiased estimate of the test set error. It is estimated internally, during the run..."

For what I know because of the way it works a RF then there is no need to use CV, but I was surprised to read that there is no need of a test set either. In that case if I want to make a classifier using RF, for example a benign or malign tumor classifier, with a dataset of n samples, is it not needed to use a separate test set and I can run the model with all the dataset? For instance in the scikit library of Python appears the following example:

```
>>> from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
>>> from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
>>> X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=4,
...                            n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
...                            random_state=0, shuffle=False)
>>> clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
>>> clf.fit(X, y)
RandomForestClassifier(...)
>>> print(clf.predict([[0, 0, 0, 0]]))
```

So, if I do not separate in a train and test set or use CV because there is no need of that, then how can I validate a model based on RF?

Comment: You are using a discontinuous accuracy scoring rule, which is a rule that can easily be fooled by a bogus model.  See [this](http://hbiostat.org/bbr/info.html#problems-with-classification-of-predictions).  It's not a good idea to use RF for classification.  Rather consider estimating of probabilities and using accuracy scores such as the Brier score.

Comment: Thanks @FrankHarrell, so does it mean that maybe many of the articles that use RF for classification could have wrong or biased results?

Comment: Yes, for two reasons.  First, RF is made for tall and thin datasets and many are using it instead for short and wide datasets; RF is extremely prone to overfitting and hard to tune.  Second, classification is seldom a good goal as detailed [here](https://fharrell.com/post/classification).

Comment: Thank you very much @FrankHarrell for your time and for the useful links